# Access Azure Storage from Azure VM without outbound internet

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have VNET with DMZ and multiple internal subnets configured. There is security requirement to block all the outbound internet connection for the internal subnets.
Now, this VM needs to access Azure blob storage which hosted in the same region. 
I am wondering to access Azure Blob storage without outbound internet connection.

Pondering on questions like
1) Can I attach Azure Storage account in my azure VNET
2) Can there is existing solution, where I am access internet via JUMP-BOX network configuration, where my VM internet traffic goes via Jump box
3) Can this be achieve via Network ACLs or some better solution?

Now, this question is mix of networking and azure services, not sure of the right forum for this, server-fault or stack-overflow?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage uses a public endpoint, as it's a multi-tenant service. You cannot add your Azure storage account to your VNet, since this is not an endpoint you control.

You'll need to access storage directly, via its `<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net` endpoint. How you ultimately accomplish that is up to you.

Comment: This is no longer the case since [VNet Service Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) have recently been introduced.